# U-boot 'nand markbad' has no effect

Tags: u-boot

Situation : board with an Arm CPU that has Nand flash next to it. On power-up, U-boot bootloader starts up and copies the flash contents to RAM, then it transfers control to that code in RAM. A Linux system with some application code, composed through Buildroot, starts running. Its entire filesystem is stored as a single UBIFS file in flash, and it starts using that.

When a certain byte is set, the bootloader keeps in control, and starts a TFTP transfer to download and store a new flash image.

Trigger : a board came back defective. Linux kernel startup clearly shows the issue:

```
[    1.931150] Creating 8 MTD partitions on "atmel_nand":
[    1.936285] 0x000000000000-0x000000040000 : "at91bootstrap"
[    1.945280] 0x000000040000-0x0000000c0000 : "bootloader"
[    1.954065] 0x0000000c0000-0x000000100000 : "bootloader env"
[    1.963262] 0x000000100000-0x000000140000 : "bootloader redundant env"
[    1.973221] 0x000000140000-0x000000180000 : "spare"
[    1.981552] 0x000000180000-0x000000200000 : "device tree"
[    1.990466] 0x000000200000-0x000000800000 : "kernel"
[    1.999210] 0x000000800000-0x000010000000 : "rootfs"
...
[    4.016251] ubi0: attached mtd7 (name "rootfs", size 248 MiB)
[    4.022181] ubi0: PEB size: 131072 bytes (128 KiB), LEB size: 126976 bytes
[    4.029040] ubi0: min./max. I/O unit sizes: 2048/2048, sub-page size 2048
[    4.035941] ubi0: VID header offset: 2048 (aligned 2048), data offset: 4096
[    4.042960] ubi0: good PEBs: 1980, bad PEBs: 4, corrupted PEBs: 0
[    4.049033] ubi0: user volume: 2, internal volumes: 1, max. volumes count: 128
[    4.056359] ubi0: max/mean erase counter: 2/0, WL threshold: 4096, image sequence number: 861993884
[    4.065476] ubi0: available PEBs: 0, total reserved PEBs: 1980, PEBs reserved for bad PEB handling: 36
[    4.074898] ubi0: background thread "ubi_bgt0d" started, PID 77
...
[    4.298009] UBIFS (ubi0:0): UBIFS: mounted UBI device 0, volume 0, name "rootfs", R/O mode
[    4.306415] UBIFS (ubi0:0): LEB size: 126976 bytes (124 KiB), min./max. I/O unit sizes: 2048 bytes/2048 bytes
[    4.316418] UBIFS (ubi0:0): FS size: 155926528 bytes (148 MiB, 1228 LEBs), journal size 9023488 bytes (8 MiB, 72 LEBs)
[    4.327197] UBIFS (ubi0:0): reserved for root: 0 bytes (0 KiB)
[    4.333095] UBIFS (ubi0:0): media format: w4/r0 (latest is w5/r0), UUID AE9F77DC-04AF-433F-92BC-D3375C83B518, small LPT model
[    4.346924] VFS: Mounted root (ubifs filesystem) readonly on device 0:15.
[    4.356186] devtmpfs: mounted
[    4.367038] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1024K
[    4.371812] Run /sbin/init as init process
[    4.568143] UBIFS (ubi0:1): background thread "ubifs_bgt0_1" started, PID 83
[    4.644809] UBIFS (ubi0:1): recovery needed
[    4.685823] ubi0 warning: ubi_io_read: error -74 (ECC error) while reading 126976 bytes from PEB 235:4096, read only 126976 bytes, retry
[    4.732212] ubi0 warning: ubi_io_read: error -74 (ECC error) while reading 126976 bytes from PEB 235:4096, read only 126976 bytes, retry
[    4.778705] ubi0 warning: ubi_io_read: error -74 (ECC error) while reading 126976 bytes from PEB 235:4096, read only 126976 bytes, retry
[    4.824159] ubi0 error: ubi_io_read: error -74 (ECC error) while reading 126976 bytes from PEB 235:4096, read 126976 bytes
```

... which causes an exception, but the kernel keeps on going, then another error is detected :

```
[    5.071518] ubi0 warning: ubi_io_read: error -74 (ECC error) while reading 126976 bytes from PEB 709:4096, read only 126976 bytes, retry
[    5.118110] ubi0 warning: ubi_io_read: error -74 (ECC error) while reading 126976 bytes from PEB 709:4096, read only 126976 bytes, retry
[    5.164447] ubi0 warning: ubi_io_read: error -74 (ECC error) while reading 126976 bytes from PEB 709:4096, read only 126976 bytes, retry
[    5.210987] ubi0 error: ubi_io_read: error -74 (ECC error) while reading 126976 bytes from PEB 709:4096, read 126976 bytes
```

... but impressively, the system still comes up alive and behaves almost fine.
*Why does the kernel not mark these flash blocks as bad ?* Those data can't be read anyway, and at least the next image flashing might skip the bad blocks...

Investigation : so the Kernel found a defective PEB #235 (decimal) in the "rootfs" partition of the flash. Each PEB is 128KB, so the error sits somewhere beyond byte 30,801,920 (decimal). Since the "rootfs" partition only starts from byte 0x800000 of the flash, the actual damaged page must be somewhere beyond byte 39,190,528 (decimal) or 0x2560000. And sure enough, when using the **nand read** utility within U-boot :

```
U-Boot> nand read 0x20000000 0x2560000 0x1000
NAND read: device 0 offset 0x2560000, size 0x1000
 4096 bytes read: OK
U-Boot> nand read 0x20000000 0x2561000 0x1000
NAND read: device 0 offset 0x2561000, size 0x1000
 4096 bytes read: OK
U-Boot> nand read 0x20000000 0x2562000 0x1000
NAND read: device 0 offset 0x2562000, size 0x1000
PMECC: Too many errors
NAND read from offset 2562000 failed -5
 0 bytes read: ERROR
```

so the damaged page sits at offset 8K within that block of flash.
From various other posts, I learned that nand flash with 2K pages organized in 128K blocks, has an extra 64 "Out Of Band" bytes over every 2048 payload bytes, bringing each page to a gross size of 2112 bytes. Anyway, the entire block of 128K will have to be disused, as this is the erase size. No problem, there is storage to spare, I just want to make sure that the next flashing will skip over this bad block.
Since neither the Linux kernel nor the bootloader bothered to mark the bad block, I'll do it by hand in U-boot:

```
U-Boot> nand markbad 2562000
block 0x02562000 successfully marked as bad
```

A similar investigation for the 2nd bad flash page reveals that the other error sits at flash address 0x60a1000 :

```
U-Boot> nand read 0 60A1000 800
NAND read: device 0 offset 0x60a1000, size 0x800
PMECC: Too many errors
NAND read from offset 60a1000 failed -5
 0 bytes read: ERROR
```

so here too, the **nand markbad** utility is used to manually put a permanent mark on this block :

```
U-Boot> nand markbad 60a1000
block 0x060a1000 successfully marked as bad
```

and to verify that everything is taken into account :

```
U-Boot> nand bad
Device 0 bad blocks:
  02560000
  060a0000
```

Just like it should be - from the start of each 128K block, both blocks are marked.

Problem : so I learned that the 64 OOB bytes are divided in 2 bytes marker, 38 bytes error-correcting code, and 24 bytes journaling. Of all the OOB bytes accompanying each 2048 payload bytes, only the very first piece of 64 bytes, accompanying the first page of 2KB, lends its 2 bytes marker code to indicate the status of the entire 128KB block. These 2 bytes should be modified *in the flash device itself* so that this status is persistent. So in my U-boot session, instead of launching the Linux system, I restarted the CPU and remained in U-boot :

```
U-Boot> reset
resetting ...
RomBOOT
 ba_offset = 0xc ...
AT91Bootstrap 3.6.0-00029-g0cd4e6a (Wed Nov 12 12:14:04 CET 2014)
NAND: ONFI flash detected
NAND: Manufacturer ID: 0x2c Chip ID: 0x32
NAND: Disable On-Die ECC
PMECC: page_size: 0x800, oob_size: 0x40, pmecc_cap: 0x4, sector_size: 0x200
NAND: Initialize PMECC params, cap: 0x4, sector: 0x200
NAND: Image: Copy 0x80000 bytes from 0x40000 to 0x26f00000
NAND: Done to load image
U-Boot 2013.10-00403-g1f9a20a (Nov 12 2014 - 12:14:27)
CPU: SAMA5D31
Crystal frequency:       12 MHz
CPU clock        :      528 MHz
Master clock     :      132 MHz
DRAM:  128 MiB
NAND:  256 MiB
MMC:   mci: 0
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   macb0
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
U-Boot> nand info
Device 0: nand0, sector size 128 KiB
  Page size      2048 b
  OOB size         64 b
  Erase size   131072 b
U-Boot> nand bad
Device 0 bad blocks:
U-Boot>
```

The bad blocks have been **forgotten** - the marker code was **not** applied persistently ?
Granted, this U-boot version seems rather old. Has the **nand markbad** utility been improved since then ?

Workaround : I modified the OOB bytes of the first page within the bad block myself. I read all 2112 bytes of the first page into RAM, then modified the 2 bytes marker code, and wrote the 2112 bytes back from RAM into flash. Technically, I should have erased the whole 128K flash page and then written back all 128K of contents. But my laziness has been challenged enough today. Nand flash can be toggled from 1 to 0 arbitrarily - it's the reverse operation that is hard, requiring an erase to restore a whole 128K page back to all-0xFF. I noticed that all the "block good" markers are encoded as 0xFFFF, so I figured that writing "0x0000" instead should suffice.

```
U-Boot> nand read.raw 0x20200000 0x2560000 1
NAND read:  2112 bytes read: OK
```

The format for **nand read.raw** is a bit quirky, as opposed to **nand.read** which expects *size* as the last argument in bytes, it wants *size* expressed in number-of-pages instead. The first page is all we need, so argument '1' does the trick. The contents, which have now been transferred to RAM, can be inspected with U-boot's **md** utility :

```
U-Boot> md 0x20200000 0x210
20200000: 23494255 00000001 00000000 01000000    UBI#............
20200010: 00080000 00100000 9cfb6033 00000000    ........3`......
...
202007e0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
202007f0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
20200800: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff    ................
20200810: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff    ................
20200820: ffffffff b0c9aa24 0008fdb8 00000000    ....$...........
20200830: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000    ................
```

Note how the **md** utility expects its *size* argument in yet a different format : this one expects it in units of words. Just to keep us alert.
The dump at address 0x20200800 clearly shows how **markbad** has failed its purpose: the 2 marker bytes of the bad block are still merrily on 0xFFFF.

Then to modify these bytes, another U-boot utility comes in handy :

```
U-Boot> mm 0x20200800
20200800: ffffffff ? 00000000
20200804: ffffffff ? q
```

It's a bit crude, I've changed the **4** first OOB bytes instead of just the **2** first marker bytes. Finall, to write the modified contents back into flash :

```
U-Boot> nand write.raw 0x20200000 0x2560000 1
NAND write:  2112 bytes written: OK
```

Funny enough, the **nand bad** diagnostic doesn't notice the block which has just been marked, even after some **nand read** attempts which *do* fail.

```
U-Boot> nand bad
Device 0 bad blocks:
U-Boot>
```

But this is no cause for alarm. The 2nd bad block was marked manually in a similar fashion, and upon another reset :

```
U-Boot> reset
resetting ...
RomBOOT
 ba_offset = 0xc ...
AT91Bootstrap 3.6.0-00029-g0cd4e6a (Wed Nov 12 12:14:04 CET 2014)
...
U-Boot 2013.10-00403-g1f9a20a (Nov 12 2014 - 12:14:27)
...
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
U-Boot> nand bad
Device 0 bad blocks:
  02560000
  060a0000
U-Boot>
```

Lo and behold, the 'bad block' marking has persisted ! The next flash storage operation neatly skipped over the bad blocks, saving a consistent kernel and filesystem in the various partitions of the flash. This was the intention all along, but it seems to require gritty manual work. Is there no automated way ?

Answer (score -1):

U-Boot has changed quite a bit since 2014. Patches possibly of relevance to your problem include:

- dc0b69fa9f97 ("mtd: nand: mxs_nand: allow to enable BBT support")
- c4adf9db5d38 ("spl: nand: sunxi: remove support for so-called 'syndrome' mode")
- 8d1809a96699 ("spl: nand: simple: replace readb() with chip specific read_buf()")

Please, retest with U-Boot Git HEAD. If there is still something missing, please, report it to the U-Boot developer list or even better send your patch.